# Как работает imblearn.under_sampling.ClusterCentroids?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, scikit-learn

Допустим, есть сильно несбалансированная выборка: `X` - признаки, `у` - целевая переменная (бинарная). Балансируем выборку с помощью метода `ClusterCentroids()` (из модуля `imbalanced-learn`), получаем новую выборку `X_cc`, `y_cc`. Берем модель, например `XGBClassifier` (для бинарной классификации), и обучаем ее на этой новой выборке. Далее берем выборку `X1` (из исходного пространства признаков `X`), для которой требуется предсказать целевую переменную с помощью обученного ранее классификатора.

**Вопрос:**
как классификатор, обученный на кластерах признаков исходного
пространства, может предсказывать целевую переменную по самим
признакам исходного пространства (не кластерам)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую описать суть данного алгоритма и как им пользоваться...

#### Суть проблемы несбалансированных данных:

Библиотека (модуль) [`imblearn` / `Imbalanced-Learn`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) предназначена для работы с несбалансированными выборками данных - такими где число образцов / экземпляров, принадлежащих *различным классам* различаются в разы. В том случае если у нас присутствует только два класса (бинарная классификация), то эти классы принято называть `majority class` (класс большинства) и `minority class` (класс меньшинства).

Классическим примером является задача выявления мошеннических транзакций. Очень часто в таких выборках доля мошеннических транзакций не превышает 1%. В таком случае даже если в качестве предсказания мы *всегда* будем маркировать транзакцию как нормальную (не мошенническую), то общая точность предсказания будет >= 99%. Подавляющее большинство алгоритмов классификации плохо справляется с обучением на разбалансированных выборках.

Если коротко, то данную проблему можно решить приблизительно уравняв число экземпляров обоих классов. Делают это обычно следующим способом:

1. уменьшив число экземпляров *класса большинства*
2. увеличив число экземпляров *класса меньшинства*
3. комбинация `1.` и `2.`

#### Суть алгоритма `imblearn.under_sampling.ClusterCentroids`:

Данный алгоритм использует алгоритм кластеризации [k-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) для нахождения [центроидов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) (геометрический центр кластера) `N` кластеров для *класса большинства*. Скорее всего, в качестве `N` берется число экземпляров *класса меньшинства*. Таким образом выбрав `N` центроидов *класса большинства* из всех экземпляров *класса большинства* мы сбалансировали обучающую выборку, оставив в ней по `N` экземпляров для каждого класса.

#### Применение алгоритма `imblearn.under_sampling.ClusterCentroids`:

В процессе обучения мы находим оптимальные коэффициенты / веса и для предсказания просто используем найденные коэффициенты / веса, подставив их в функцию алгоритма классификации. (Мы об этом не заботимся - готовые реализации классификаторов делают это за нас.)

Поэтому *теоретически* нам достаточно сбалансировать только обучающую выборку, обучить модель и дальше можно использовать обученную модель без балансировки.

*На практике* перед тем как использовать непосредственно классификацию, данные необходимо предварительно подготовить. Обычно подготовка состоит из следующих шагов:

- `imputing missing data` - заполнение или удаление отсутствующих данных (например: `None`, `NaN`, пустые строки и т.д.), т.к. большинство алгоритмов классификации или не работают или плохо справляются с отсутствующими данными.
- `encoding non-numerical data` - преобразование нечисловых данных в числовые.
- `data scaling & normalizing` - калибровка (скалирование и нормализация) данных
- `classification` - непосредственно классификация.

Чтобы объединить все шаги подготовки данных и классификации часто используют `pipeline`:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("impute", imputer),
    ("encode", encoder),
    ("scale", scaler),
    ("classify", classifier),
])
```

и потом используют объект `pipeline` для обучения и классификации:

```
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

В этом случае, как видно из примера, данные по которым мы делаем предсказание пройдут все шаги предварительной обработки, которые испольовались для обучения.

---

**PS** некоторые моменты в ответе могут показаться слишком очевидными автору вопроса. Я постарался подробно ответить на вопрос, чтобы ответ оказался полезным и понятным также тем кто попадет сюда по ссылке поисковика.